# Как запустить активность с другого приложения?

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, android-intent

Есть приложение А, которое должно запустить активность с приложения Б.
Пытался сделать вот так, но не работает.

```
Intent myIntent1 = new Intent();
myIntent1.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.example.messer.myapplicationb", "com.example.messer.myapplicationb.MainActivity"));
myIntent1.putExtra("param1", myEditText1.getText().toString());
startActivity(myIntent1);
```

Comment: Вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150003/how-to-export-an-activity-so-other-apps-can-call-it

Comment: Работает, спасибо.